# unmatched close parenthesis on Facebook video url

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I'm trying to use a facebook video regex string. However, when I load the view I am getting an unmatched parenthesis error.. even though I am using an example string from the below example:

https://www.regextester.com/94995

Here is my Ruby function that aims to match the regex ..

```
  def get_fb_id(url)
    match = url.match(/^?:(?:http|https):\/\/)?(?:www.)?facebook.com\/(?:(?:\w)*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?([\w\-]*)?\/(?:[\w\-]*)?\/([\w\-]*/)
    match[:id] if match.present?
  end
```

If anyone can spot an error here please notify me. Thanks

Comment: Try `url.match(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/(?:\w*#!\/)?(?:pages\/)?[\w-]*\/[\w\-]*\/[\w\-]*/)`, see [here](http://rextester.com/EVD26645). You have `^?:` at the start, it is an error, and there are some redundant groupings here.

Comment: You are missing an opening parenthesis at the beginning `^(` and one at the end `*)`